# How to set redis connection timeout?

Tags: redis

Where in the configuration file do I set the connection timeout for Redis?

I know there is a timeout setting in the config file, but that only applies for idle connections. I want the timeout to apply when I want to read from redis. I want it to time out only after N seconds, rather than the default.

Comment: Is it possible that what u want is the data you store to time out and not the connection?

Comment: No that is not it. That would be trivial.

Comment: It is set on client side, not server side. It therefore depends on the client library you use.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone who is still looking for this, on a redis connnection string you can specify connectTimeout like below.

```
<add key="RedisConnectionString" value="your-redis-server,abortConnect=false,connectTimeout=1000,ssl=false,,password=your-password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

On console of redis set this configuration

```
config set timeout 300
```

Comment: What you suggest is a server-side setting. OP asks for a client-side setting, where the client keeps watching if a server does not respond. Your suggested setting works the other way around, the server would disconnect a client if the client does not respond. These are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

- You basically need a **read-timeout**
- This will be a client side property
- Mention this in your application.

---

I'll examplify for Laravel framework of PHP

specify it at database.php file ('read_timeout' => 60)

```
    'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'read_timeout' => 60,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: its worked for me 'read_write_timeout' => 0